# Unable to fix dual boot (grub menu)

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, dualboot, pop-os

I have dual boot with Windows10 and Pop OS, after last upgrade of Pop OS appeared grub menu and I only be able to continue writing "exit". After that boots in Pop OS (Ubuntu based), but I cannot boot in Windows.

I've tried "Recommended repair" using boot repair application and what suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732060/im-stuck-at-grub-menu-and-cant-boot-to-ubuntu)

I don't know how to proceed to fix this. Thanks for any help

*Addition*

I've received this output from **boot repair**

```
Boot successfully repaired.

Please write on a paper the following 
URL: https://paste2.org/
```

Comment: Post link to Summary Report from Boot-Repair. Do not post report.

Comment: That is not a full link from Boot-Repair's summary report.

Comment: Is Internet on when you run it? this is an old one, they delete the data after a while, but show what it should be: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CzxWhfzQgb/  The last characters are unique to each post/report.

Comment: I installed boot repair in Pop OS and then I run it directly in computer. There are no unique characters in summary report after `org/`. Then could be a bug in "boot repair" report that is not showing the unique URL

Comment: Boot-Repair may not then recognized the pastebin site when PopOS. You can manually open a pastebin and copy entire report there. Report should have copy in /var/log/boot-repair. You want the .txt file, not a log file.

Comment: @oldfred I have run it again and there is no txt file. It creates a `boot-repair.log` and `boot-repair.logb`. Besides that generates a folder named  `sda` and generates folders named `sdaX`, where X goes from 1 to 8. Inside those `sdaX` some are empty and others have files but any of them is .txt file

Comment: then for some reason it is not creating file. Check log. PopOS may not have some required supporting file that most distributions have. I mostly see Ubuntu and have seen Fedora work. I thought I did see a PopOS before also, but not sure.